# including an external php library in a Drupal 7 module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, include, libraries

I'm trying to include an external php library (oauth2-server-php) in my drupal site, so I can use it in a custom module. I installed the Libraries 2.x module so I can put the external php library in sites/all/libraries.

Whenever I try to call `libraries_load('oauth2-server-php');` in my module, it throws the following error:

```
Call to undefined function libraries_load()
```

What is the correct way of including a php library in a custom module?

Comment: Did you make sure the Libraries module is installed and enabled?

Comment: Yes it is. It loads css and js libraries without problems.